# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DCountry'

Tags: python, django

I am getting the captioned error whenever i try the below code:

```
DCountryObj = DCountry.objects.filter(CountryCode=NewInputRefObj.CountryCode).get()
```

I dont quite understand what its talking about because I am simply taking the countrycode from one object  to use in a filter for another model object creation. See relevant models:

```
class DCountry(models.Model):
    CountryCode = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Country = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    SPI = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Country
```

NewInputRefObj refers to  a object made from the following model:

```
class InputRef (models.Model):
    CountryCode = models.ForeignKey(DCountry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Please point me in the right direction for what I should try here because i dont understand why its saying it has an issues with int()???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused as to what you are trying to achieve. Why not just use `NewInputRefObj.CountryCode` since it refers to the related `DCountry` object through the foreign key?

I think if you wanted that query to work you would have to follow the chain of related objects/attributes. When you filter DCountry by CountryCode, you need to pass in an integer, but `NewInputRefObj.CountryCode` is actually the related `DCountry` object, hence the error since it expects an `int` or something that can be cast to an int using `int()`, but receives `DCountry` instead.

You'd would have to use `NewInputRefObj.CountryCode.CountryCode` to get the `primary_key` `IntegerField` you are actually trying to filter on:

```
dcountry_obj = DCountry.objects.get(CountryCode=NewInputRefObj.CountryCode.CountryCode)
```

But again, you're better off just getting the related object in that case using `NewInputRefObj.CountryCode`, since you're filtering on a unique primary key and there can only be a single object returned from that query anyways, i.e. the one linked by a `ForeignKey` relationship.

Comment: Great explanation. Just came with same results on shell here.

Comment: @Niloct Thanks! Nice to see you understood the problem the same way. Gives me more confidence in my own answer =)

Comment: Ohhhh brilliant thanks for the explanation as well. 

The reason why I am doing this is that the DCountry model object has a SPI field and thats the value I actually need (the two models are seperate for another reason). In the next step i use the SPI value to do something else.Is there a better way to achieve that tho? As I am all for learning and am ACUTELY aware how inefficient etc I am lol.

Answer (score 1):

Try this line:

```
DCountryObj = DCountry.objects.filter(CountryCode=NewInputRefObj.CountryCode.CountryCode).get()
```

or just

```
DCountryObj = NewInputRefObj.CountryCode
```

It seems that when you are calling first `.CountryCode` you get the `DCountry` object, then you have to query its property `.CountryCode`.

### EDIT

(Then query `DCountryObj.SPI` =) )

Comment: Beat me in content, not in timing :) Same results though.

Comment: oh yeah ur right i just refreshed and it switched u guys around and updated the time.